# Should I retry through Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have some old code, implementing retry to an Azure Service Bus topic using the [EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling/) package:

```cs
var bus = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(con, topic);
await new RetryPolicy<ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(
    new FixedInterval(3, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)))
    .ExecuteAsync(() =>
        await bus.SendAsync(msg)
        ...
```

The code is written years ago and probably taken from a blog post or some Microsoft documentation. When inspecting today's `TopicClient`, it contains a property named `RetryPolicy`, which as default is set to an instance of `RetryExponential` with some default values for the number of retries, max timeout, etc.

In my eyes, the default retry strategy on `TopicClient` looks good. Are there any benefits in wrapping this in retries using TransientFaultHandling? If I want more retries or another retry strategy, I can simply configure another retry strategy directly on the topic client, rather than wrapping two retry strategies together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can simply configure another retry strategy directly on the topic client, rather than wrapping two retry strategies together.

That's why `RetryPolicy` found with Azure Service Bus .NET client was created with ability to reconfigure it to match your needs. You don't have to introduce a 3rd party retry, unless you really need it for cases where buil-in retry policy doesn't do what you need.